# Building angular application and putting on the server

Tags: angular, build, angular6, ng-build

I'm developing an angular6 application and I want to generate a build to test on my server, currently I use ng server and it runs working on my browser without generating any errors.

> c:\Users\emiry\Desktop\Angular\Projects\StartingNewProject

when I run the `ng build` command it generates a build for the /dist folder and returns no errors

on my machine I have installed `wamp64` so I get this build generated by ng and put it in my www folder

> C:\wamp64\www\StartingNewProject

Just this would be enough for me to be able to run my application on the server?

when I try to access my application that is on the server through the http:// localhost/startingnewproject/

it returns me the following error in the browser console

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) polyfills.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) styles.js:1 Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 (Not Found) main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the
>   server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "StartingNewProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/StartingNewProject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              {
                "input": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "StartingNewProject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "StartingNewProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "StartingNewProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "StartingNewProject-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "StartingNewProject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "StartingNewProject:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "StartingNewProject"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "starting-new-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-alpha.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

I tried to access as follows

> file:///C:/wamp64/www/StartingNewProject/index.html
>
> 5index.html:13 GET file:///C:/runtime.js 0 () /C:/favicon.ico:1 GET
>   file:///C:/favicon.ico 0 ()
>   translate.google.com/gen204?nca=te_li&client=te_lib&logld=vTE_20180625_00:1
>   GET
>   file://translate.google.com/gen204?nca=te_li&client=te_lib&logld=vTE_20180625_00
>   0 ()
>
> file:///C:/wamp64/www/StartingNewProject/index.html
>
> GET file:///C:/runtime.js 0 () /C:/favicon.ico:1 GET
>   file:///C:/favicon.ico 0 ()

When I try to access the root directory to see the folders and files, I can perfectly, the problem is when I load the index.html

Comment: If you paste `C:\wamp64\www\StartingNewProject` or `C:\wamp64\www\StartingNewProject\index.html` into your browser, does that load the application?

Comment: Hi, I tried to access and I had some problems, I put the results I got in the question

Comment: Okay, so it looks like it can at least find the file, which is good. Have you checked that your wamp64 service is running and that it is configured with apache correctly?

Comment: yes, in my wamp I also have my api to connect with this my angular project and when I execute the ng serves in angular I can access the api correctly

Comment: If you just browse to `http://localhost`, does the WampServer homepage show? (not your Angular Homepage)

Comment: yes, the page is displayed normally and in Your Projects the StartingNewProject appears

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought the 404 was for the entire Angular app, but it's not. It's just for the relative paths, which is due to the `base` tag. I've added an answer below for you

Comment: Okay, I'll try to execute the method you reported.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The issue that the project is having is in trying to find it's dependencies. The `index.html` file of your Angular project should contain a tag that looks like:

```
<base href="/">
```

Or similar. That means, when it looks for dependencies, it looks for the relative to the root. In your case,there not next to the root (i.e. localhost), they're under `StartingNewProject`

You can should generate a new build with `ng build --prod --base-href=/StartingNewProject/` which will add the base href tag for you. Please note that it is important to include both the leading and trailing slash here.

More details can be found in the Angular docs, [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not understand where do I find this <base tag? if I do not change and run ng build --base-href = / StartingNewProject will work?

Comment: Yep, you can run that build command without needing to change the HTML manually

Comment: I run the ng build command -base-href = / StartingNewProject and when I go to http: // localhost / startingnewproject / it returns me GET http: //localhost/runtime.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: If you manually open `C:/wamp64/www/StartingNewProject/index.html`, can you see the `<base>` html tag? Is the `href` attribute set to `"/StartingNewProject"`?

Comment: I just manually add the index.html <base href = "/ StartingNewProject"> file and the error continues

Comment: when I created my project I added the --routing and also added the bootstrap scheme, does this have any problems?

Comment: You added it to the one in `C:/wamp64/www/StartingNewProject/index.html`, yes? And there shouldn't be any space in there. Make sure you remove the space. And no, there won't be any issue with either of those things.

Comment: I created a new build of my project and put it in the folder C: / wamp64 / www /. the tag is <base href= "/StartingNewProject">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177133/discussion-between-user184994-and-emiry-mirella).

Comment: for me, I remove the <base> tag in index.html file and insert {provide: APP_BASE_URL, useValue: '/'} in provider property of @NgModule in AppModule.js file and tried to build the project to make it work.

Comment: I have the same issue, but already added base tag with <base href="/myapp/"> and still got 404 cause I think the scripts src should also contain the relative path, something like this:
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js"></script>
how can I solve this?

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same problem. I fixed this using `./`.

```
<base href="/"> to <base href="./">
```

again build and deploy.

Answer (score 2):

you may get a "deprecated" warning with Angular 11 when using

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/StartingNewProject/
```

You can instead adjust angular.json.

In angular.json file, create a "baseHref" property like this:

```
 "projects": {
   "your-project-name" : {
          "architect": {
             "build": {
               "options": {
                   "baseHref": "/your-relative-path/"
```

This will change the URL both in production and development.

Beware that, in your links, always use relative paths like this (instea of "/"):

```
 <img class="top-bar__logo" src="./assets/images/picture1.svg" />
```